# curl POST works in command line but not with Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I need to run a `curl POST` to obtain API token as following:

```
curl - i -v -k -X POST -d '{"authType":"LOCAL","password":"mypw","username":"admin"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" "https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/myapi_auth_path/login"
```

Everything runs well and I can obtain the token.

Now I want to do that with Python `requests`:

```
import requests

address = "https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/myapi_auth_path/login"
    
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
data = {"authType": "LOCAL",
        "password": "mypw",
        "username": "admin"}

res = requests.post(address, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

I get this error:

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What is wrong with the Python code?

Comment: We need a [mre] -- code complete enough to let someone else see the problem themselves and test their solutions; that's very much not the case here -- the code is stubbed out enough to be completely untestable.

Comment: Consider using something like [postbin](https://www.toptal.com/developers/postbin/) to log a server's view of POST requests from both clients and compare. Once you know what it is that's different, you can ask a more narrow/specific question about how to fix that thing.

Comment: BTW, `-k` / `verify=False` defeats the point of using https; I strongly urge reconsideration.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on ```-k```. I was going to deal with that after this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `data=data` which means your data dict will be form-encoded.

You can use `json=data` instead (this will also set the `Content-Type` header for you)

It's covered [in this section of the docs,](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: Thanks. This works.